What is Tone Mapping Operator?
Can the Tone Mapping Operator (TMO), whether global or local, be commonly understood as processing the XYZ values of all pixels in the input image, with the TMO handling each set of XYZ values and then outputting the processed XYZ? Is it typical for each point's XYZ values to be multiplied by the same factor? If so, how are the factors for different points determined?
I have been exploring various Tone Mapping Operators (TMOs) in different HDR processing tools. I tried to understand how both global and local TMOs work by reviewing documentation and experimenting with different algorithms. My expectation was that the TMO would apply a uniform scaling factor to all pixel XYZ values globally, or in the case of local TMOs, use different factors based on some local image characteristics like luminance or contrast.
However, it’s unclear to me how these scaling factors are determined, especially for local TMOs where different regions may need different adjustments. I was expecting to find a consistent pattern or method for calculating these factors but have not yet come across a detailed explanation.
